# Give a geometric interpretation of | I | = 1 for I the identity matrix.

Tags: geometry, matrices

Can anyone help me in giving a geometric interpretation of | I | = 1 for I the identity matrix.?

Comment: the notation "$|I|$" is nonstandard.  "$\|I\|$" is much more common.  It means the norm of $I$.  There are several popular matrix norms.

Answer (score 2):

the volume of any cube living in any integer dimension with sides $1$ is always $1$

Answer (score 0):

The columns represent the standard basis in any dimension.  The length of each basis vector is 1.  Hence the volume of the n-cube with sides 1 is always 1.